# Live streaming on azure with FMLE

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to stream to the new azure live channel.
I have followed the guide on http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/18/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/

this is my FMLE setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8rlk.png
but for some reason I am getting disconnected by the azure service. I am using Flash Media Live encoder 3.2 and this is what the log looks like:

```
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:30 : Video Encoding Started 
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:39 : Primary - Network Status: NetConnection.Connect.Closed status
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:45 : Primary - Disconnected
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:48 : Primary - Re-establishing connection, attempt 1
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:48 : Primary - Reconnected
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:48 : Primary - Network Command: onBWDone
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:48 : Primary - Stream[mystream9] Status: Success
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:48 : Primary - Stream[mystream9] Status: NetStream.Publish.Start
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:56 : Primary - Network Status: NetConnection.Connect.Closed status
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:58 : Video Encoding Stopped
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:33:58 : Session Stopped
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:01 : Primary - Disconnected
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:01 : Audio source does not support the selected sample rate and/or channels. Re-sampling the audio to desired setting.
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:02 : Primary - Re-establishing connection, attempt 1
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:02 : Primary - Reconnected
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:05 : Primary - Network Status: NetConnection.Connect.Closed status
Thu Oct 09 2014 16:34:05 : Primary - Disconnected
```

Edit:
Oh well I decided not to go for azure live streaming. Reasons are many. They let you only output to mpeg-dash which frankly is not ready for the world as of now. There are few players who support that out of box. Because of the smooth streaming crap from microsoft, we the encoders, are forced into limiting our encoding options. Alot of encoding software today dont have all the option that is required to stream such as frame alignment, grouping of pictures etc. Its kinda sad that I can stream with h264 but not x264 which is opensource and better.

Comment: Have you also created and started a program, not just channel?

Comment: yes it does that automatically nowadays whne you start the channel. i did check it manually aswell, there was a program created.